# How do references in Java work?

Tags: java, reference, linked-list

When we insert a node to the head of a linked list, we can use the following code:

```
Node oldfirst = first;
first = new Node();
first.item = "not";
first.next = oldfirst;
```

and the definition of Node is as follows,

```
private class Node
{
    Item item;
    Node next;
}
```

My question is since in java, object variables are references, then oldfirst and first should always point to the same node. If that's true, it cannot insert the node to the head. Where am I wrong?

I also found such codes in solving the problem "merge two sorted lists":

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {

    ListNode p1 = l1;
    ListNode p2 = l2;

    ListNode fakeHead = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode p = fakeHead;

    while(p1 != null && p2 != null){
      if(p1.val <= p2.val){
          p.next = p1;
          p1 = p1.next;
      }else{
          p.next = p2;
          p2 = p2.next;
      }

      p = p.next;
    }

    if(p1 != null)
        p.next = p1;
    if(p2 != null)
        p.next = p2;

    return fakeHead.next;
    }
}
```

In the above codes, p is the reference of dummyHead, so when it returns, p has been changed, is dummyHead.nex still the head of the merged list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are variables themselves, they simply point to an address in memory.

In your case, **oldFirst** and **first** are different references that point to the same object, that's why when you set **first** to point to something else, **oldFirst** is unaffected, because it's a different reference, in fact it's ***a copy*** of the **first** reference, but not the same reference.

If you still don't understand look at the 'int' data type, you can have int a = 10; and int b = 10; both ints "point" to the same integer, when you set a to equal to 12, b is unaffected, references work in the same way.

In C# you can pass references by reference and by value into functions (you can't pass by reference in java). So if you have a function:

```
void Foo(ref SomeType x); // pass by reference
```

in the scope of the function *Foo* you will have the same thing that you passed into this function, so if you reset x to point to something else you will have changed what you passed into this function.

However if you wrote this:

```
void Foo(SomeType x);
```

then x will be passed by value, meaning x will be a copy of the reference you passed into the function *Foo*, and if you reset it to point to something else it won't affect the reference that you passed into that function.

Answer (score 1):

This will explain:

```
Node oldfirst = first;  // oldFirst points to the same node as first
first = new Node();     // first now points to a new node.
                        // oldFirst stays pointing to the original first node
first.item = "not";     // update the item of the new first node
first.next = oldFirst;  // .next of the new node points to the old original first node
```

So this code inserts a new node at the start of the list.